# How to clean url wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, clean-urls

I'm using wordpress for a site,

this url before tes.com/index.php/about/
i want url like this tes.com/about/

I have tried copying parts of WordPress' .htaccess, however shows a 404 error.

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas on where to start and how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Usually for Wordpress, [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)  plugin would do. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your WP-ADMIN-->Settings-->Permalink and use the permalink structure change there, if it generate any .htaccess file copy the content and update your .htaccess file.

Or Check if your hosting mod_rewrite is enable by creating a file phpinfo.php with content,

Upload this file and browse via Browser. So you know which modules are enabled. You need mod_rewrite enable to remove index.php from URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /test.com/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /test.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [official instructions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) will give you clean urls. So best to follow this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```